# TYPO3 Extbase Extensions: Where do i find the MySql database tables for each class of the extension?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, typo3, extbase

Simple question (perhaps):

I'm developing a TYPO3 extension. Where in PHPMyAdmin can i find the tables for records of each class of the extension? I need to actually read/access the tables and their data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: look for "tx_myextension_*"

The tables and/or fields of an extension are declared in "ext_tables.sql" in the root folder of the extension.
in general all tables should start with the extension name prefixed with "tx_". For extbase the name might include something like 'domain', 'model', ...
If you use ext:extension_builder the names are generated automatically like "tx_myext_domain_model_myextdata"

---

edit:
[image]
here you filter the shown tables or paginate to the tables on other pages.

Comment: I know, i was searching for these specific tables in phpMyAdmin, but i just can't find them.

Comment: then your problem is not TYOP3 but phpMyAdmin: in newer versions the listing of the tables is paginated and you need to page to the later pages to find tables with alphabetic late names. Alternative you can filter the list of tables, or select a table on the full listing of all tables in the right main panel at the start

Comment: i never said that TYPO3 was the problem. Bu yeah, i just filtered phpmyadmin for the table name and found them. Sometimes you dont see the woods because of the trees.^^

Comment: I'm sorry about that... But i've experienced a strange behaviour of TYPO3: Whenever i delete a record in the backend, it doesn't get deleted in the DB table. I still see it in phpmyadmin. Is that normal behaviour? Is there a way around this?

Comment: it is normal. TYPO3 does not really delete records but marked them as deleted (see field `deleted`). so you can reactivate records from trashbin with the recycler. be sure: in normal queries (= done with the official core functions) the deleted records are not shown.

Comment: also there are scheduler jobs (garbage collectors) which remove (=really delete) all records marked "deleted" after some time. but you probably will not save much space, as databases often stay with blanked space of these records until new records will use this space.

Comment: Ah OK, that complicates things for me, since i actually intended to query the specific MySql tables with an external script outside of TYPO3... Anyway, thank you very much for the clarification. This helps a lot.

Comment: if you want to do queries outside of TYPO3 you have a lot of fields to consider (and add them to your external query). beside the field `deleted` there are fields `hidden`, `starttime`, `endtime`, `sys_language_uid`, `version`, `workspace`, `fe_group` which control the visibility according to further conditions. search for "enablefields"

Comment: Ah... Well as i can just select entries where deleted is not set to 1 it's easy enough for me now. Thanks again.